# How can I use the Courier plugin to notify a user when an entry is enabled?

Tags: emails, status, frontend-form

Moderation scenario:

1. Registered user publishes an entry using a front-end form that sets the entry to `disabled`.
2. Moderator receives email re new entry and changes status from `disabled` to `enabled` in the CP.
3. User receives email informing them that the entry has been enabled.

I’ve got steps 2 & 3 working using both the Courier & Postmaster plugins independently. However, when the user edits their entry via another front-end-form, they also receive an email notification.

How can the user be notified **only** when the entry has been edited **and** the entry's status has been changed from `disabled` to `enabled`?

Courier blueprints:

Step 2: Triggers: `entries.onSaveEntry` and Conditions: `{{ entry.sectionId == '3' and isNewEntry ? 'true' : 'false' }}`

Step 3: Triggers: `entries.onSaveEntry` and Conditions: `{{ entry.sectionId == '3' ? 'true' : 'false' }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Courier Blueprint listen to `entry.beforeSaveEntry` events and use this code for the Trigger Condition:

```
{% set oldEntry = craft.entries({
    id: entry.id,
    status: null,
}).first() %}

{%- set wasDisabled = oldEntry.status == 'disabled' %}
{%- set isEnabled = entry.status == 'live' %}

{{- wasDisabled and isEnabled ? 'true' : 'false' }}
```

Comment: Thanks Christian!

I got it working as follows:
    
    {% set oldEntry = craft.entries.id(entry.id).status(null).first() %}
    {%- set wasDisabled = oldEntry.status == 'disabled' %}
    {%- set isLive = entry.status == 'live' %}
    {{- entry.sectionId == '3' and wasDisabled and isLive ? 'true' : 'false' }}

I had to change `enabled` to `live`.

Comment: Glad to hear, Andrea. I updated the answer accordingly.